# What use cases are there for Early Media with IVRs?

Tags: telephony, ivr

I would say that the following are valid use cases for Early Media when used for IVRs:

1. Filtering

   Disconnect incoming calls based on certain criteria (such as callers from a specific area code, or to play a message before hanging up on after hour callers).
2. Rate limiting

   For example to limit the number of simultaneous callers, where the excess calls are either disconnected, or placed in a queue. (I'm not sure if the queue example is possible though without answering the call.)

Are there more?

---

Some links that were helpful:

- https://www.dialogic.com/webhelp/csp1010/8.4.1_ipn3/sip_software_chap_-_early_media.htm
- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Early+Media+and+the+Progress+Application
- https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Early+Media

Answer (score 1):

3) Legal: in some countries it is illegal for a call center using payed line (caller pay per minute) to accept a call without sending it straight to an agent. So you can't accept the call, give the user some waiting music for 15 minutes (and make them pay for the privilege of waiting as well).

Result: you don't accept the call. However, this creates a new problem: if the caller only hears the ring back tone for those 15 minutes, he/she will assume no one will answer and hangs up.

Using early media, you can give them the traditional "your call is very important to us, please hold on"-type of experience without accepting the call and without starting to charge money. Of course this also depends somewhat on how much the provider is willing to tolerate, as this can also affects their income (depending on their own business model).

4) Comfort: you may not be aware of this, but the sound you hear as caller when the other side is ringing (ring-back tone), is not universally the same throughout the world. A company with a global number may wish to use early media to provide a ring-back tone more familiar to you, depending on where you are calling from. It was always a bit niche of a concept but some target audiences are statistically more likely to hangup if they hear an unfamiliar sound. 15-20 year ago this might have been a concern to some, but in the era of smartphones and internet calls, I doubt anyone really worries about it anymore.

Comment: Thank for these awesome bits of info! [Our service](https://societyfortheblind.org/programs-services/access-news/) (that we are replacing right now) is behind an 800 number, and has no human operators, so I didn't even think of call center & legal implications. Item 4, as you say, may not be relevant anymore, but opens up new possibilities of what else could be done.